# Playground authorization endpoint results in error: "insecure_transport"

Tags: authlib

First of all, great work. I donated because this could really save me lots of headaches. New to oauth2 and authentication in general. I signed up and registered @ https://play.authlib.org/, added newapp. When I tried to authorize with the following uri:

> https://play.authlib.org/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=FhHzedZ9kdtQeTQRCwTgZELPdnHCEfEo7K0771U9XircD9Hh&state=e3dC66BGid2z0IwBinMgLKJ92IiD1r

it failed with:

> {
>       "error": "insecure_transport",
>       "error_description": "OAuth 2 MUST utilize https."
>   }

Am I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code. The server itself has a bug (just fixed).

The playground is powered by Authlib v0.5 now.

---

You need to learn how to send requests for client_credentials:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4.2

```
 POST /token HTTP/1.1
 Host: server.example.com
 Authorization: Basic czZCaGRSa3F0MzpnWDFmQmF0M2JW
 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

 grant_type=client_credentials
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have only so far successfully completed the authorization code flow from your documentation, and not password nor client_credential. Is that expected of the current WIP?

Comment: @DarrenLiu Oh. There are typos in the playground codebase. https://github.com/authlib/playground/commit/a90e428795aa4e4b7500d473578144d317d5a929

Comment: still failing. This was the request for password: https://play.authlib.org/oauth2/token?grant_type=password&username=xxx@gmail.com&password=xxx

Comment: this one for client_credentials: https://play.authlib.org/oauth2/authorize?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=FhHzedZ9kdtQeTQRCwTgZELPdnHCEfEo7K0771U9XircD9Hh&client_secret=IyiKX4bNuBoICu0nFKiz8Fj6aKOfR3tmYWYLKRWImLFsf0cMVMHvyaAqAgtpXkhUJTCzvCJb7EuK0D

Comment: I have tried the same for /oauth2/token endpoint. They all yield: {
    "error": "invalid_grant"
}

Comment: @DarrenLiu you need to learn how to make requests for client_credentials and password.